# Service calls to multiple dao methods

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ibatis

I have a Service class such as following:

```
@Transactional
@Component(value = "userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
  @Autowired
  private UserDao             userDaoiBatis;

  public boolean X()
  {
    // Call UserDao.A and UserDao.B in transaction.
  }
}
```

And a Dao class such as following:

```
@Transactional
@Component(value = "userDaoiBatis")
public class UserDaoiBatis extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements UserDao
{
  @Autowired
  private void injectSqlMapClient(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient)
  {
    setSqlMapClient(sqlMapClient);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean A()
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean B()
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
  }
}
```

How can I call UserDaoiBatis.A() and UserDaoiBatis.B() as part of a transaction in userServiceImpl.Z() ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have setup looks correct. The transaction will be started by `UserServiceImpl` then both calls to `UserDaoiBatis` will inherit the existing transaction (`@Transactional` defaults to REQUIRES propagation). You can confirm this by enabling debug level logging on the `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` class.

Note that with `A()` throwing an exception, the tx will rollback.

Comment: Thank you Sir, just needed the confirmation.

Comment: +1 with a note that you usually don't really want DAO methods to be @Transactional.

Comment: Understood, not all my Dao's are transactional. Just a few which might anticipate an incoming transaction. OR am I missing something here?

Comment: You don't have to have @Transactional on DAOs since the calling service   started the transaction. But, it's a good safety net in case you call a DAO directly. If you want to ensure you don't call DAOs directly, you could set the DAO tx level to MANDATORY which will throw an exception if a tx isn't already running.